# NSManagedObjectContext hierarchy when saving

Tags: core-data

I've seen some examples where you do something like:

```
_model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
_coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_model];

_context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType]; // THIS IS THE MAIN CONTEXT
[_context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

_childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [_childContext setParentContext:_context];
    [_childContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    [_childContext setUndoManager:nil]; 
}];
```

Then you can insert an item into in the child context in your views, typically a modal view.  When the user hits cancel, the object is only in the child context and never gets saved at that moment so it's easy to create temporary NSManagedObjects and discard them until you save both contexts.  Is there any reason why you couldn't do this:

```
_parentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [_parentContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_coordinator];
    [_parentContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
}];

_context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_context setParentContext:_parentContext];
[_context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
```

Now you insert stuff into the parentContext.  Then when you save, you first save the _context (main context), and then that bubbles up to the parentContext?  It seems to work in code, but I didn't know if there was a reason why the examples I see are all having the objects inserted into a childContext where the main context is the parent.

Or is there a better way to handle the use case of hitting Add Item, showing a modal view with that new NSManagedObject that was created for this view.  That's the way the bulk of the sample code I see is to create a new item when your "Add Item" view is being shown.  Problem is if you hit Add Item, hit Cancel, then hit Add Item again, you'll now have two NSManagedObjects floating around in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recommends that contexts that save to disk be of a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` type, which is also suitable for UI operations, such as fetches and display. The reason for this is unclear, but from experience, you should really follow this, so have your main context of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Now, if you add an object to the parent context, these changes **do not bubble up** to the child context. This is why you always want data to flow toward the main context and insert in child contexts. In your second example, if you add an object to `_parentContext`, but your UI is listening for changes on `_context`, it will not hear of new objects being added or objects being changed.

Note, that if you intend to create a temporary child context for passing data to and from UI, create the context as a child with concurrency type of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` so you can set properties directly from the main thread, rather than having to `performBlock:` them.

My current approach, instead of creating a context and working directly with an object, I use a dictionary and "bind" my data to that. Only once the user saves, I create a new object, transfer the data to the object from the dictionary and save. Not sure if it matters, really, as child/parent contexts make such throwaway operations very cheap and easy.